# How to style button with input

Tags: html, css, button, input, colors

I am trying to align the button text to center but it is not moving up. It is located slightly below.
I want it to be placed in center with the input type color.

```css
button{
  outline: none;
  background: #cccccc;
  border: none;
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  padding: .6rem 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input[type="color"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="strokecolor">Choose a color
  <input type="color" value='#1a1a1a'>
</button>

<!--Choose a color text is not getting to the center of the button
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the button as `display: flex` and use `align-items: center`

```css
button{
  display: flex; /* This is new */
  align-items: center; /* This is new */
  outline: none;
  background: #cccccc;
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  padding: .6rem 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input[type="color"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px; /* This is new */
  height: 20px;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="strokecolor">Choose a color
  <input type="color" value='#1a1a1a'>
</button>

<!--Choose a color text is not geeting to the center of the button
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
button{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  outline: none;
  background: #cccccc;
  border: none;
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  padding: .6rem 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input[type="color"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="strokecolor">Choose a color
  <input type="color" value='#1a1a1a'>
</button>

<!--Choose a color text is not geeting to the center of the button
```